# Getting exception while fetching current sheet 'package.Workbook.Worksheets exception'

Tags: c#, excel

```
using OfficeOpenXml.ExcelPackage

var currentSheet = package.Workbook.Worksheets;--throws exception on this line
```

> exception:- package.Workbook.Worksheets =
> 'package.Workbook.Worksheets' threw an exception of type
> 'System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException'

What can be the possible reason for this?
Is there any other way to do the same?

Comment: Maybe there are no sheets present in the excel file?

Comment: Looks like you are assigning all worksheets to a single worksheet.  Try: `var currentSheet = package.Workbook.Worksheets[1];`

Comment: You can also assign a specific sheet by name:  `package.Workbook.Worksheets["Sheet1"];`